# How do I create an npm package from an existing one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm relatively new to node and the npm package system. For my redux/react web application, I currently use the `photoswipe` package in combination with `react-photoswipe`. Now I wanted to add some extra functionality to the photoswipe package, so I went into the `photoswipe` folder in the `npm-modules` folder, made the required changes and ran `npm build` in there.

This works, but the changes will of course be lost as soon as for whatever reason the `node_modules`-folder gets deleted and recreated, or if I upgrade the photoswipe package.

What is the correct workflow in this case? Can I somehow clone the existing package, change it, then store it in something like a local repository that npm recognizes? Thanks alot for clarification!

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the license of the `photoswipe` package. If it is open source then I would highly recommend that you open a pull request with your changes so that everyone benefits from your feature :)

That being said, you can always clone the package, make your changes and reference the `photoswipe` package from *your* github repo. For e.g.: `npm install github:alex-cory/fasthacks`

Comment: `npm install github:alex-cory/fasthacks` could be shortened to `npm install alex-cory/fasthacks`